# Avoiding over-printing for publication quality figures

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a full-page figure to publish. The figure looks great on my screen device using Cairo.  I've struggled and struggled to get it saved nicely as a file that I can submit.  I'm close, as well as I can articulate it, my points and lines just blob together.  It's not a resolution issue because as I zoom in, everything looks better and better.

Here is how I make one panel (drawing from two different data frames):

```
ggplot()+
  geom_line(aes(df1$Date, y=df1$sw_10), colour = "black", size=.25) +
  geom_point(aes(df2$Date, y=df2$sw_10),fill="white",colour="blue",pch=21, size=1) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("white"))+
 ylim(0.1,0.4)+
        theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
          panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
          panel.background = element_blank(),
          axis.line = element_line(),
          legend.position='none', legend.title=element_blank(),
          legend.text = element_text(size=12),
          axis.title.x = element_blank(),
          axis.title.y = element_blank(),
          axis.text.x = element_blank(),
          axis.text.y = element_text(colour="black", size=12))
```

Then I put them together with grid and output as an eps:

```
postscript("figure.eps", width=8.5, height = 11)
print(fig)
dev.off()
```

And here is the result:

[figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CAwyX.png)

or, as the .eps: https://www.dropbox.com/s/zo3rsnv7tuvg1a6/tryit.eps?dl=0

Is there any obvious way to improve this?

Comment: You have linked to a png object so we do not know how you got from the postscript file to what you are displaying. It's probably an effect of how you are viewing your file.

Comment: I was trying to get it posted on here so it would just pop up with out a link.  I printed it as a pdf and imgur changed it to a .png, but it doesn't look a whole lot different than as an .eps.  Please open the dropbox file if you can.

Comment: Saying "my points and lines just blob together." does not help very much. The eps figure displays with high fidelity on my machine so perhaps you are just seeing an effect of a relatively low resolution monitor?

Comment: Do you see distinctions between the points when it is at an 8.5x11 size?  For me, it looks great when it is blown up, but when it is at the size it will be printed, it is hard to tell the differences within points and between points and lines.

Comment: Yes. I do. Even at a size less than 11x8.5 I see distinct points. There are some where the distinction is lost by over-printing, but you cannot possibly expect to resolve every points when there are so many close together. This is really something you should be discussing with the publisher.

Comment: Okay, great.  My screens are at least 8 years old.

Comment: Mine is 6 years old but standard equipment on Macs were generally better than on non-Macs at any particular time in the last 15 years :-)

Comment: Although I have to admit I was hoping for something more like "increase the contrasts between your lines and points", "decrease the outline size on your points", "layer other shapes as outlines over your points", "print it really big, then shrink it".  Maybe better asked as ways to avoid over-printing?

Comment: And I was hoping for clarity of question. Furthermore, it seems to have absolutely no R content.

Comment: Try experimenting with the opacity of various plotted elements. This is often helpful to compare density of observations. http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/aes_colour_fill_alpha.html  It may also help to use a different color for the line versus the points. The apparent point outlines I find distracting and noisy.